# How to make my Android app resolution suit all devices?

Tags: android, android-drawable

When creating an app using eclipse, is it enough for me to just put the same image file into the files in the drawable folder? Will android make it suit the device automatically? Or should I manually create different images with different resolutions and then put it under the drawable folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

**Yes**, android will scale your images to devices.

Long answer:

Yes, android will scale the images but...
The scaled images look pretty bad on lower resolution devices and 
If you are unable to produce all the preffered drawables (xxhdpi xhdpi mdpi hdpi), I suggest you atleast put in the biggest version so it will be scaled down (xxhdpi). Preferably together with a hdpi version, because of the bad scaling on lower resolution screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put different resolution image to different folder then better to put only HD image to hdpi folder and create the layout dynamically in java file using weightSum attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can use eclipse `android icon set` to create your icon for different DPIs

- Right click on your project & Select `New` and then `other`.
- In the `type filter text` section type in `android icon set`.
- Select `Android Icon Set` from and click on `Next`.

Now You can create your icon